# Check if a list contains a string. Contains asks for a class object

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm reading a json file to a list using the following code:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("rep.json");
var repList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<rep>>(json);

public class rep
{
    public string userid;
    public int repValue;
}
```

Now I'm trying to check if the replist contains a specific userid using the following code:

```
if (repList.Contains(user.AvatarId.ToString()))
{

}
```

But this `contains` method accepts a object from the rep class. How could I check this since i don't know the users rep values?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead for `.Contains` you have to make a try with `.Any()` Which will returns a boolean value which represents the presence of any matching items. That is the condition will be true if any `rep` in `repList` with `userid` as `user.AvatarId`

```
if (repList.Any(x=> x.userid == user.AvatarId.ToString()))
{
   // code your logic here    
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked fine!! Any idea how i could add a rep class object to the repList ?

Comment: Happy to help you..! Yep you can use `Add()` to add an item to the List `repList.Add(new rep(){userid="USR001",repValue=10});`